# Angular 15 upgrade broke reactive forms

Tags: angular-material, angular-reactive-forms, angular15

I've recently upgraded our large Angular project to 15 using nx migrate. Ours is a nx monorepo. We chose to have the deprecated Angular material components as there are so many style changes. After upgrade wherever Angular material or custom form controls are used it throws [image]. ***When native form input is used there is no error.***

As I debugged I noticed **NG_VALUE_ACCESSOR** is null for the Material Form field or custom form control. It works in Angular 14.